# How can i working push view controller on swift 5?

Tags: swift

Didselect function in CollectionView or TableView;

```
let trial = TrialViewController ()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController (trial, animated: true)
```

I want to move to the other page, but it does not respond. The same thing is working when I type.

```
self.present (den, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

is working when I type.

why pushViewController not working?

Thnx

Comment: what is `den` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems `self.navigationController?` is `nil`

**With storyboard:**

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController (trial, animated: true)
```

make sure the current vc is embedded inside a navigationController

[image]

**without storyboard:**

inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(root:ViewController())
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but i don't use storyboard.

Comment: Embedding in navigation controller didn't help. It is working fine in iOS 12, but not in iOS13.

Answer (score 1):

Your current ViewController is not RootViewController.

In AppDelegate,

set this code:

```
var  mainView = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstScreenVC") as! FirstScreenVC
self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
```

Now run your code,
Because now the current controller is rootViewController.

Comment: Isn’t this the same as checking the “Initial View Controller” box in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You should not instantiate a view controller like this `TrialViewController ()`

Instead, use:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "SbName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VcID") as? TrialViewController
```

Comment: the op says the `present` works with him , so this isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't use storyboard. My class is here;

```
     import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        setupViews()
        //register collectionview
        collectionView.register(AppCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    let topView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return view
    }()

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        return cv
    }()

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setTitle("Buton", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    @objc func handleButton() {
        print(1212)
    }

    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(topView)
        topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        topView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(button)
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 15).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! AppCell

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height * 0.2)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let trial = Trial()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(trial, animated: true)
    }
}

class AppCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        setupViews()
    }

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setTitle("Buton", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    @objc func handleButton() {
        //statusShow.showSettings()

    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(button)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width * 0.3).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.height * 0.2).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class Trial: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```